# JavaFX issues to build an artifact and jar

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, artifact

I'm using Gradle build system in intellij
I tried to create an artifact and build jar in intellIj , but there are 3 issues i encountered:

1)go to project structure/artifacts create an jar with type JavaFX application. Entered path to main class. Artifact was created but faced with " Can't build artifact - fx:deploy isn't available  in this JDK" (I'm using JDK 21)
[image: issue n1]

Tried build a classic JAR .

2. Created an jar artifact with selected option "JAR files from libraries extract to target JAR" then tried to launch it and got this error: `no main manifest attribute, in D:\Projects\mobileExam\out\artifacts\mobileExam_jar\mobileExam.jar` .By the way i have an manifest in JAR.[image: issue n2]

3)Created an jar artifact with selected option "JAR files from libraries copy to the output directory and link via manifest" then tried to launch JAR and got this error `Invalid or corrupt jarfile D:\Projects\mobileExam\out\artifacts\mobileExam_jar2\mobileExam.jar`. Why gradle corrupted my JAR? I'm using gradle 8.5.[image]

Here is my manifest:

```
Main-Class: com.english.mobileexam.mobileexam.Launch
Class-Path: junit-platform-engine-1.10.0.jar javafx-fxml-21-win.jar ikon
 li-javafx-12.3.1.jar ikonli-core-12.3.1.jar formsfx-core-11.6.0.jar jun
 it-platform-commons-1.10.0.jar javafx-swing-21-win.jar tilesfx-11.48.ja
 r javafx-controls-21.jar bootstrapfx-core-0.4.0.jar javafx-controls-21-
 win.jar javafx-base-21.jar javafx-base-21-win.jar javafx-graphics-21-wi
 n.jar validatorfx-0.4.0.jar javafx-web-21-win.jar junit-jupiter-api-5.1
 0.0.jar javafx-media-21.jar controlsfx-11.1.2.jar junit-jupiter-engine-
 5.10.0.jar opentest4j-1.3.0.jar javafx-graphics-21.jar javafx-media-21-
 win.jar
```

My build.gradle file

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
  id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.english.mobileexam'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

ext {
  junitVersion = '5.10.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = '21'
targetCompatibility = '21'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
  mainModule = 'com.english.mobileexam.mobileexam'
  mainClass = 'com.english.mobileexam.mobileexam.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
  version = '21'
  modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.web', 'javafx.swing' ]
}

dependencies {
  implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
  implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.6.0') {
    exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
  }
  implementation('net.synedra:validatorfx:0.4.0') {
    exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
  }
  implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.3.1')
  implementation('org.kordamp.bootstrapfx:bootstrapfx-core:0.4.0')
  implementation('eu.hansolo:tilesfx:11.48') {
    exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
  }

  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()}

jlink {
  imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
  options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
  launcher {
    name = 'app'
  }
}

jlinkZip {
  group = 'distribution'
}
```

Comment: The three approaches you describe are all using IntelliJ's own system for creating the JAR file. But you are using Gradle, and so you should be having *Gradle* build the JAR file. The simplest way is to just execute the Gradle `jar` task. That will package your project's classes and resources in a JAR file under `build/libs` by default. You can customize the task (e.g., adding manifest attributes) by modifying the Gradle build script. It's possible to customize the task to build a JAR with dependencies, but I would use the *Gradle Shadow Plugin* for that.

Comment: Note you can have IntelliJ execute Gradle tasks for you, either by creating an appropriate run configuration or by opening the Gradle tab and choosing a task to run.

Comment: See the [runtime images](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) selection of the openjfx.io getting started instructions, th e[packaging section of the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info), the [badass runtime plugin](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) and  [Idea gradle integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html).  You are unlikely to be using all of those dependencies. I advise you only place the dependencies you need in your gradle build file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, i just executed gradle task "jlink" in my project and got image in build/image then i run .bat file in image/bin and my app runs!
[image]  I wanted to create an executable build of my project. So , i don't need jar anymore. Credits to [jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea)!

Don't use intellij's build jar artifacts with javaFX and gradle build system, it's just broken.